# Is it correct to say 'what price is it?'

Tags: grammaticality

I think it is ok to say 'how much is it?' or 'what is the price of it?', but can I say 'what price is it?'

Also, why sometimes we can both use 'what xxx is it' and 'what is it's xxx' but sometimes we can't. For example we can say 'what nationality are you?' but we cannot say 'what job are you?'

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your best form is "How much is it?" if you want a natural sound. For "What is the price," it is better to ask "What is the price of ABC" or just "What is the price?" Asking "What job are you?" is making me equal to a job, and you want to know which one. Well, I *am* American, but I *do* a job. I am not my job.

Comment: A very interesting question, Rui Lu. There are some examples where the 'What N ...' form is the more idiomatic. 'What size are these shorts?' / 'What day is it today?'  I'd say that 'What nationality are you?' is less so (Ngrams seem to show a 50-50 split between 'what nationality are you' and 'what is your nationality').  'What temperature is he?' appears (in a Google search) to be far less common than  "What is his temperature?". "What temperature is it?" can't be easily researched as _it_ may be 'weather it'.

Comment: Your nationality is an indivisible part of who and what you are. Your job is something you do, which could change tomorrow…